# Line not removing after adding code with data pulling in from a query and import range formula in google sheets

Tags: jquery, google-sheets-formula, delete-row

I imported data into a google spreadsheet from a google form spreadsheet using a query and import range formula. I did this because I only wanted specific columns from the original dataset.

In the spreadsheet, I want the row of data to stay on the first tab until a drop down is selected as "not hired". When that drop down is selected, I want the row of data to move to the Not Hired tab. I used code to delete the row on the first tab, and it did add the data onto the Not Hired tab, but the information in the deleted row was pulled back into the first tab, so row of data was then on the first tab and the Not Hired tab.

How do I get the data to not re-appear on the first tab after the drop down is selected to move it to the Not Hired tab?

I pulled the information in with a query and import range formula, and that seems to be working well.

I am 'deleting' the row and moving it to the Not Hired tab with the following code. It is moving the data, and the row deletes for a second then it is re-added to the first tab.

`function onEdit(e) { const src = e.source.getActiveSheet(); const r = e.range; if (src.getName() != "Working Pipeline" || r.columnStart != 15 || r.rowStart == 1) return; const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Not Hired"); src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,29).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,29)); dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(),30).setValue(new Date()); src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);`